# Oracle - Different count clause on the same line

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I wish I could find a request allowing me to have on the same result line, 2 values obtained with a different clause:

For example, let's say that I have this table:

```
ID   |VAL
----------
0    |    1
1    |    0
2    |    0
3    |    1
4    |    0
5    |    0
```

I wish I could, in the same request, select the number of lines having val = 1, the number of total lines, (and if possible the total percentage of one count on the other) which would give result set like this:

```
nb_lines | nb_val_1 | ratio
---------------------------
6        |     2    |   0.5
```

I tried something like:

```
select count(t1.ID), (select count t2.ID
                     from table t2 where t2.val = 1
                     )
FROM table t1
```

But obviously, this syntax doesn't exist (and it wouldn't give me the ratio). How could I perform this request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query which uses CASE to count only those rows we need.

```
SELECT nb_lines,nb_val_1,nb_val_0, nb_val_1/nb_val_0 FROM
 (SELECT COUNT (t1.ID) nb_lines, 
        COUNT (CASE
                WHEN t1.val = 1
                  THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
               END) nb_val_1, 
        COUNT (CASE
                WHEN t1.val = 0
                  THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
               END) nb_val_0
   FROM tabless t1);
```